# How to use Angular $animate optional options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

According to the Angular docs for the `$animate` service, all methods have an optional `options` parameter with the description *an optional collection of styles that will be applied to the element.*

Looking for a description an example of how to use `options`.

Docs: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$animate

Comment: Does it add the CSS class to the element?

Comment: Yes, it adds the `added` class to `someElement` on the DOM.